# sqlite eclipse save keypair to database, get keypair from database

Tags: sqlite, select, return, resultset

I save the keypair to database in bytes:

```
byte[] pubkey = pair.getPublic().getEncoded();
byte[] privkey = pair.getPrivate().getEncoded();


  String sql = "INSERT INTO certs(name, pubkey, privkey) VALUES(?,?,?)";

    try (Connection conn = connect();
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        pstmt.setString(1, name);
        pstmt.setBytes(2, pubkey);
        pstmt.setBytes(3, privkey);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

This works. But when I want to get a key from the database it doesn't.

```
public static byte[] getPubKey(String name){
          String sql = "SELECT pubkey FROM certs WHERE name = ?";
            byte[] result = null;

            try (Connection conn = connect();
                 Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();
                 ResultSet rs    = stmt.executeQuery(sql)){
                result = rs.getBytes(1);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            return result;
      }
```

It returns:
ResultSet closed 
null

How can I fix this? And how can I format the keys back to a normal key format?

Answer (score 0):

The SELECT query needs a parameter.

Comment: pubkey is my query?

Comment: added this pstmt.setString(1, name);   Now it works.